# Python3 Minidom Parse Data Inside Tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, xml-parsing, minidom

I am trying to pull the numbers out the  tags of this XML file:

```
<start-date type="date">1980-12-12</start-date>
<end-date type="date">2018-05-04</end-date>
<data type="array">
  <datum type="array">
    <datum type="date">2018-05-04</datum>
    <datum type="float">178.25</datum>
    <datum type="float">184.25</datum>
    <datum type="float">178.17</datum>
    <datum type="float">183.83</datum>
    <datum type="float">56201317.0</datum>
    <datum type="float">0.0</datum>
    <datum type="float">1.0</datum>
    <datum type="float">178.25</datum>
    <datum type="float">184.25</datum>
    <datum type="float">178.17</datum>
    <datum type="float">183.83</datum>
    <datum type="float">56201317.0</datum>
  </datum>
```

Using this script:

```
#Test Parser

from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('AAPL.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('datum')

print(len(itemlist))
print(itemlist[0].attributes['type'].value)
for s in itemlist:
    print(s.attributes['type'].value)
```

But the output returns what type is = to so it returns float, array, and date over and over but I need the numbers inside the tag datum
Like this:

```
<datum type="float">178.25</datum>
```

I need the 178.25 value 
How can I change my script to do this
This is my first parser project so I am a bit lost here. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact you did not present a valid XML data (because there is no root element), suggests different ways to resolve your problem. But all these methods are very similar and rely on the use of [`nodeValue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.html#node-objects). Below is a solution.

We suppose we have your valid XML file (and I know you have one):

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> xmldoc = minidom.parse('AAPL.xml')
```

From there, we will look for elements which have *datum* as a tag name:

```
>>> datums = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('datum')
```

`datums` is a list of all the XML document objects which have have the tag name *datum*; and this actually include the one you do not need: their parent node `<datum type="array">`.

We thus loop over these `datums` (and exclude the parent one) to display their text.

Note that the text *178.25* below is a child node of `datum` element.

```
<datum type="float">178.25</datum>
```

That is why we need to loop as follows:

```
>>> for datum in datums:
...     if datum.getAttribute('type') != 'array': #exclude the parent datum
...             print(datum.childNodes[0].nodeValue)
```

As datum has a list of child nodes which consists only of one element (the text element) we need to write `datum.childNodes[0]` to access it. Once we position ourselves in that text element, we can read its content by invoking `nodeValue` mentioned previously.

And here is the output:

```
>>> from xml.dom import minidom
>>> xmldoc = minidom.parse('AAPL.xml')
>>> datums = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('datum')
>>> for datum in datums:
...     if datum.getAttribute('type') != 'array':
...             print(datum.childNodes[0].nodeValue)
... 
2018-05-04
178.25
184.25
178.17
183.83
56201317.0
0.0
1.0
178.25
184.25
178.17
183.83
56201317.0
```